# Raspberry PI: Counting the raising and falling edge at a frequency?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio, edge-detection

I am reading this 1/0 pulse on a GPIO physical pin 22 and I am trying to count the number of pulses occurring in the frequency of 100. I have two questions:

1. I am reading and detecting the edges successfully. But failing to figure out the rest (counting the number of pulses).
2. Also, how do I print 1s continuously to the shell until 0 is detected and print 0s until 1 is detected? Presently, it prints 1/0 only when the edge is detected. Why? I want to see the square wave output rather than the triangle output (below screenshot) in the Thonny plotter.

[image]

Comment: Seems like you shouldn't be using an edge detection event, just repeatedly printing the GPIO state.

Comment: @importrandom some times you think too much this is what happens. We go searching for miles and hours by forgetting the solution we have at hand. You are truly amazing. thanks

Comment: @importrandom how to count the signals? any idea?

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26169/74873) or [this one](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24815/74873).

Comment: @importrandom Okay, this is something closest I found after two days of searching. Thanks a ton. Looks like the two frequency counters are available in C. Do you think, the same script and methodology works for Python as well? Thanks a ton

Comment: I imagine you'll be able to get a similar approach working in python. If it's not working out I would try the [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) daemon in the second link above, it has python bindings.

Comment: First of all, forget about custom libraries like _pigpio_, it is a non-scalable way. Use generic _libgpiod_. Second, do not use Python for this, it's wrong even for 100 Hz, since Linux is not an RTOS. Third, don't buy the polling approach, it's prone to lost or misinterpret events, what you need is the IRQ event monitor and better to be implemented in the Linux kernel (something along PPS subsystem).